# Возможно обновлять товары в AliExpress через код с помощью файла?

Tags: php

Нашёл документацию как можно обновить товары через загрузку YML-файла (https://sell.aliexpress.com/ru/__pc/YML_AE_Assistant.htm). Но это делается вручную, возможно автоматизировать обновление товаров через YML-файл (или другой способ), например раз в сутки?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под делается в ручную? Не знаком с тем как работает aliexpress, но я так понимаю там можно дать ссылку на xml файл который будет каждый день обновляться автоматически а ваша задача только обновлять этот файл на сервере генерируя файл автоматически.

Comment: Например крон ..